# How to get no of rows data into single array of another table row using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have one table `product_size`: `product_id`, `size`, `size_id`

another table `product`: `product_id`, `productname`

I want to get output like below.
ex:-

```
productname, [20, 25 , 30]
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what `[20, 25 , 30]` really is. I've posted my answer and then thought that it could mean something else, so I've posted another one... Please, check if one of them is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what `[20, 25 , 30]` really is. I could think of two possible answers, here they goes:

Assuming that `[20, 25 , 30]` are `size_id`s, here is a query:

```
SELECT
    productname,
    array_agg(size_id)
FROM
    product
    JOIN product_size
    USING (product_id)
GROUP BY
    productname;
```

See [documentation on Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html).

---

Assuming that `[20, 25, 30]` are dimensions of the product, like `[length, width, height]`:

```
SELECT
    productname,
    ARRAY[
        (SELECT size FROM product_size WHERE product_size.product_id = product.product_id AND size_id = 'x'), 
        (SELECT size FROM product_size WHERE product_size.product_id = product.product_id AND size_id = 'y'), 
        (SELECT size FROM product_size WHERE product_size.product_id = product.product_id AND size_id = 'z')
    ]
FROM
    product;
```